# Different behavior of Apache Camel aggregation in IDE and when deployed in JBoss Fuse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I'm having a problem with Apache Camel that I can't understand. I have this issue with JBoss Fuse 6.3.0, which bundles Apache Camel 2.17.0.redhat-630224.

I have a simple route: it downloads files from an FTP server, transforms them into POJOs (this part works), then aggregates them into a single POJO which is marshalled and saved to a file.

In JBoss Developer Studio, I test this by doing "Run as... > local Camel context". Behind the scenes, this simply runs `mvn clean package org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:run`. Whether I do it from the IDE, or manually in my terminal, the route works fine.

However, when I build an OSGi bundle (with `mvn clean install`) which I then deploy into JBoss Fuse (Apache Karaf), the application deploys successfully and the download/transform parts works fine, but then the aggregation fails.

The aggregation is handled by a custom class that implements `org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy` (documented [here](https://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html)). The problem I have is that the `newExchange` parameter I receive always have a null body. Now, the `oldExchange` being null the first time is expected, but the `newExchange`'s body? (edit: the correlation expression is a simple constant, since all POJOs are aggregated together)

Even weirder: if I modify the route to marshall my POJOs just before the aggregator, I receive a String with the expected data. This proves (I think!) that the transformations work as expected. Also, Fuse's logs show no error messages (neither at deploy time nor at runtime). This looks a lot like a configuration or dependency issue, but for the life of me I can't find any similar issue reported anywhere.

Has anyone ever seen something similar before? Or at least, do you have any tips as to what could be the problem's source?

Edit: here's the relevant part of the route:

```
<choice>
    // one <when> per file which produces a POJO
    <when id="_when_some_xml">
        <simple>${file:onlyname} == 'something.xml'</simple>
        <to id="_to2" uri="ref:transform_something_xml"/>
    </when>
</choice>
// if I add a marshalling here, I receive non-null exchanges in the aggregator... but they're strings and not the POJOs I want.
<aggregate completionSize="12" id="_aggregate_things"
            strategyMethodAllowNull="true" strategyRef="MyAggregator">
    <correlationExpression>
        <constant trim="false">true</constant>
    </correlationExpression>
    <log id="_log_things_aggregated" message="Data aggregated."/>
    <convertBodyTo id="_convertBodyTo_anotherClass" type="net.j11e.mypackage.MyClass"/>
    // [...] next: marshal and save to file
```

Note: I tried with strategyMethodAllowNull="false", didn't change a thing.

And here's the Aggregator:

```
public class EpgAggregator implements AggregationStrategy {

    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
        // first message being aggregated: no oldExchange, simply keep the message
        if (oldExchange == null) {
            System.out.println("Old exchange is null");
            return newExchange;
        }

        if (newExchange.getIn().getBody(MyClass.class) == null) {
            System.out.println("newExchange body is null");
        }

        // ...
```

The second `if` triggers every time, even for the first aggregation, if I remove the `return` in the first `if`.

**Edit**
Ok, so thanks to noMad17n's comment below, I had a breakthrough: the problem has to do with class loading.

When I got the `newExchanges`'s body without specifying a class (`Object newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody();`), the result was not null, but I couldn't cast it as `MyClass`: I got a `java.lang.ClassCastException: net.j11e.MyClass cannot be cast to net.j11e.MyClass`.

Reading about how OSGi can lead to multiple classloaders loading the same class, I renamed `MyClass` to `MyOtherClass` and after a reboot (??), everything worked. However, after uninstalling my bundle and reinstalling it, the problem is back.

`osgi:find-class MyClass` returns two bundles: mine and dozer-osgi, which is (I guess) logical since MyClass instances are produced by a dozer transformation.

Ok, so maybe I should not uninstall and reinstall bundles very often but use `osgi:update`, `osgi:refresh`, or whatever. But still, there should be a way to make this work? Something else than uninstalling my bundle, refreshing/updating dozer, stopping/restarting Fuse, and reinstalling my bundle, hoping that one of the aforementioned operations somehow makes the correct classes be loaded?

Comment: The cusom class is part of the same bundle that is being deployed I presume? How do you do the deployment?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti yes, the custom Aggregator is in the bundle. I can check that by checking the artifact produced by maven - and also because the calls to System.out.println I put in the aggregate method appear in my logs when the application runs ;)

Comment: Is your Camel newer than 2.16 on your Fuse installation?

Comment: It would be interesting to see your actual route(s) as well.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti: yes, it's Camel 2.17.0.

Comment: Like @noMad17 mentioned, is it possible to see the actual route code?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti: I edited my post yesterday to add the relevant portion of the route and the beginning of the aggregator component. Do you need anything more? Knowing that when I save my objects to a file right before the aggregator, I get correct data, I assume this means the <choice> part works as intended...

Comment: Are you sure the body is actually null? I have a feeling that it might be that the body is not actually of the type "MyClass" (which I suspect is actually called something else). What happens if you change the second if to `if (newExchange.getIn().getBody() == null)`?

Comment: @noMad17: if I remove the body type, the newExchange's body is not null!  I'm not very familiar with Java, so I don't really know how I can inspect what I get if I type it as an Object. I tried casting it manully (that is, `MyClass newBody = (MyClass) newExchange.getIn().getBody();`), and that fails with a `java.lang.ClassCastException: net.j11e.MyClass cannot be cast to net.j11e.MyClass`. I'll look into it. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @noMad17: I updated the post with what I found since my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might encounter this issue in the future, here's a recap:

- the problem is caused by the fact that an older version of a package exported by your bundle is still used by another (in my case, dozer-osgi). Here, this causes the cast to MyClass to fail, which makes `getBody` return null (`getMandatoryBody` would return an exception, etc.)
- to identify the bundle causing the issue, use the command `osgi:find-class MyClass`. This will return your bundle... and another.
- refresh that bundle by finding its bundle id (`osgi:list | grep thebundle`) and refreshing it (`osgi:refresh 123`). You can also refresh the bundle from Fuse's web UI (hawtio): OSGi > bundles > your bundle > the refresh button at the top of the page (next to the start, stop, update, and uninstall buttons).

That's more a mitigation than a proper solution to this issue. The real solution would probably involve fixing the package import/export rules or something, but this is beyond my current skills.

Fair warning, too: sometimes, refreshing dozer-osgi apparently wasn't enough. MyClass was not imported by it anymore (`osgi:find-class MyClass` would not return dozer-osgi), but I still had my `NullPointerException` problem. In these rare occurrences, I had to restart Fuse. I don't know why these few cases happened.